# Compare a value to a range using arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to compare a value to a range of values that is **in the formula and not on the sheet itself**.

For example, I want to compare 2 to {1,3,5} to check which one is bigger.

```
  A B C
1 2 1 =formula()
2   3
3   5
```

If the range was on the sheet, I would just do something like `= arrayformula(A1 >= B1:B3)` , resulting in { TRUE, FALSE, FALSE }.

```
  A B C
1 2 1 TRUE
2   3 FALSE
3   5 FALSE
```

Then, I want to do the same thing except that the range is created via functions like filter() or index(). Obviously I cannot just B1:B3 as they are not on the sheet itself. What should I do to achieve the same result without using scripts?

[Example link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lpyFIgve2_vI0YiqGYoDASsL9GBUZk7rpvHqXkrusps/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Show what you already tried.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lpyFIgve2_vI0YiqGYoDASsL9GBUZk7rpvHqXkrusps/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

If you'd want to return the rows of the base table that meet both conditions ('Fruit' and >= 2) you can use

```
=QUERY(B6:D9, "where C = 'FRUIT' and D >= 2", 0)
```

or

```
=filter(B6:D9,C6:C9="FRUIT", D6:D9>=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=FILTER(B6:B9, C6:C9="fruit", D6:D9>=B19)
```

[image]